# Error building Docker image for Blazor WebAssembly project with shared references

Tags: docker, containers, blazor-webassembly

I create a solution with 4 poject, I'm facing difficulties when trying to build a Docker image for my Blazor WebAssembly project. My project has shared references that are located in specific paths.

My project structure:

CNCCentral.Shared (Class library with entities for data manipulation)
CNCCentral.Server.Api (ASP.NET Core API for manipulating SQL Server data)
CNCCentral.Client.Shared (Razor SDK with Razor components and client services that consume the API)
CNCCentral.Client.Web (Blazor WebAssembly application that uses pages from the Client.Shared project):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rma2o.png)

I create a docker image for CNCCentral.Server.Api and works normaly. But i need create a image for front end blazor web assembly.

I did the docker file:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY ["CNCCentral.Client.Web.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "CNCCentral.Client.Web.csproj"
RUN dotnet publish "CNCCentral.Client.Web.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish


FROM nginx:alpine AS final
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY --from=build /app/publish/wwwroot .
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

And nginx.conf:

```
events { }

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    server {
        listen 8080;
        server_name localhost;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html;
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
        }
    }
}
```

But when i try to build a docker image in ter
`docker build -t cnccentralclientweb:dev .`

and i have this problem:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTBso.png)
"The reference project ..\CNCCentral.Client.Shared\CNCCentral.Client.Shared.csproj does not exist"
"The reference project ..\CNCCentral.Shared\CNCCentral.Shared.csproj does not exist"

However, all the references are valid, and the project compiles successfully when using the dotnet watch command locally.

I would like to understand why Docker is unable to find the references during the image build and how I can resolve this issue.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

In my attempt to build a Docker image for my Blazor WebAssembly project, I followed the steps outlined below:

Created a Dockerfile with the necessary instructions for building the image.
Specified the base SDK image and set the working directory.
Copied the project files and performed a dotnet restore to restore the packages.
Copied the shared project reference (CNCCentral.Client.Shared.csproj) to the appropriate location.
Ran dotnet publish to generate the output files in the /app/publish directory.
Defined the final stage using the NGINX runtime image.
Set the working directory and copied the published files from the build stage.
Copied the NGINX configuration file (nginx.conf).
My expectation was that the Docker build process would complete successfully, generating the Docker image with all the necessary files and dependencies.

However, during the build process, I encountered the following error:

"The reference project ..\CNCCentral.Client.Shared\CNCCentral.Client.Shared.csproj does not exist"

This error suggests that Docker cannot find the reference to the shared project, even though the project structure and references are valid. Strangely, when I use the dotnet watch command locally, the project builds without any issues.

I'm seeking guidance on why Docker is unable to locate the shared project reference during the image build and how I can resolve this error.

Comment: You copy only the csproj `COPY ["CNCCentral.Client.Web.csproj", "./"]`, you must copy ALL of your source files.

Comment: i did this:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY ["./CNCCentral.Client.Web.csproj", "./"]
COPY ["./CNCCentral.Client.Shared/CNCCentral.Client.Shared.csproj", "./CNCCentral.Client.Shared/"]
COPY ["./CNCCentral.Shared/CNCCentral.Shared.csproj", "./CNCCentral.Shared/"]
COPY . .

but the appears an error saying it failed to copy. 

failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref: "CNCCentral.Shared.csproj"